# How to Change the Month Name English to Arabic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In Below my codepen link i have event Calendar which fetch English month directly but i wanted change its month name to Arabic

For example :
February needs to be changed to "فبراير"

Codepen Link : [Click Here](https://codepen.io/jabirgct/pen/xxEOmrq)

```
$('.b-calendar__header .month').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('February', 'فبراير')); 
});
```

I tried This way but not working

Please Help

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: If you need just Arabic language, you can create an array like month[0] = "arabic for January", month[1] = "arabic for February" and then you `month[date.getMonth())` or 
something like: `new Date().toLocaleString('ar-AE', { month: 'long' })`. I don't know your code to help you integrate these two ideas

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is Usefull for you

```js
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar', { month: 'short' });
const month1 = formatter.format(new Date());
console.log(month1);
```

Comment: const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar', { month: 'short' });
const month1 = formatter.format(new Date());

console.log(`${month1} `);

Comment: @JabirSayed it's working fine ..please try again